# How to deal with Support Vector machine and text data when there are multiple text features to input?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am working on NLP project where I have multiple features to provide to SVM model. All the features to input are in text. If there was only one feature to input we can provide that feature as X and corresponding label as Y for training model but how can I supply more than one feature as X input for the model?
[Dataset Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX8LH.png)

For now I am trying to pass the parameters 'Questions' and 'WhWord' as input and 'CoarseType' as label. As they are text data I have to apply TfidfVectorizer before applying algorithm.It looks like the TfidfVectorizer doesn't supports the idea of X= multiple features. How can I handle this? Here is what I was doing.

```
features=['Questions','WhWord']
X = df.loc[:,features].values
y = df.CoarseType
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TEST_SIZE, random_state = 42)
model = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=1, kernel='sigmoid'))),   
               ])
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

could you show your dataset for better understanding your problem.
As of my understanding on your problem-
you can simply create it like X= all parameters using loc function and  Y= target and then use it into algorithms like model.fit(X,Y) (here I wrote model only for you to understand)

Comment: "could you show your dataset for better understanding your problem"- this is a comment, so remove this line and place it in the comments section

Comment: I have updated the question with dataset format and few code snippet. Could you help me now?